# Is it possible to create "parallel sets" plot using R? 

Tags: r, data-visualization, categorical-data, interactive-visualization

Thanks to Tormod question (posted [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11892/plotting-changes-in-a-three-valued-ordinal-variable-across-two-time-points-using)) I came across the [Parallel Sets](http://eagereyes.org/blog/2009/parallel-sets-released.html) plot.  Here is an example for how it looks:
[image]
(It is a visualization of the Titanic dataset.  Showing, for example, how most of the women that didn't survive belonged to the third class...)

I would love to be able to reproduce such a plot with R.  Is that possible to do?

Thanks, Tal

Comment: For ideas on graphics, I always check the R graph gallery. Here's something from there that is somewhat like what you ask for: [R Graph Gallery parallel](http://addictedtor.free.fr/graphiques/RGraphGallery.php?graph=37). I found it by clicking parallel in the tag cloud, but there may be better options.

Comment: Thanks Nick.  But this will not work for categorical data without major tweaking of the code (it's also probably not the best base of functions to built this with).  I hope someone might have done something similar already...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here's a version using only base graphics, thanks to Hadley's comment.
(For previous version, see edit history).

[image: third try]

```
parallelset <- function(..., freq, col="gray", border=0, layer, 
                             alpha=0.5, gap.width=0.05) {
  p <- data.frame(..., freq, col, border, alpha, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  n <- nrow(p)
  if(missing(layer)) { layer <- 1:n }
  p$layer <- layer
  np <- ncol(p) - 5
  d <- p[ , 1:np, drop=FALSE]
  p <- p[ , -c(1:np), drop=FALSE]
  p$freq <- with(p, freq/sum(freq))
  col <- col2rgb(p$col, alpha=TRUE)
  if(!identical(alpha, FALSE)) { col["alpha", ] <- p$alpha*256 }
  p$col <- apply(col, 2, function(x) do.call(rgb, c(as.list(x), maxColorValue = 256)))
  getp <- function(i, d, f, w=gap.width) {
    a <- c(i, (1:ncol(d))[-i])
    o <- do.call(order, d[a])
    x <- c(0, cumsum(f[o])) * (1-w)
    x <- cbind(x[-length(x)], x[-1])
    gap <- cumsum( c(0L, diff(as.numeric(d[o,i])) != 0) )
    gap <- gap / max(gap) * w
    (x + gap)[order(o),]
  }
  dd <- lapply(seq_along(d), getp, d=d, f=p$freq)
  par(mar = c(0, 0, 2, 0) + 0.1, xpd=TRUE )
  plot(NULL, type="n",xlim=c(0, 1), ylim=c(np, 1),
       xaxt="n", yaxt="n", xaxs="i", yaxs="i", xlab='', ylab='', frame=FALSE)
  for(i in rev(order(p$layer)) ) {
     for(j in 1:(np-1) )
     polygon(c(dd[[j]][i,], rev(dd[[j+1]][i,])), c(j, j, j+1, j+1),
             col=p$col[i], border=p$border[i])
   }
   text(0, seq_along(dd), labels=names(d), adj=c(0,-2), font=2)
   for(j in seq_along(dd)) {
     ax <- lapply(split(dd[[j]], d[,j]), range)
     for(k in seq_along(ax)) {
       lines(ax[[k]], c(j, j))
       text(ax[[k]][1], j, labels=names(ax)[k], adj=c(0, -0.25))
     }
   }           
}

data(Titanic)
myt <- subset(as.data.frame(Titanic), Age=="Adult", 
              select=c("Survived","Sex","Class","Freq"))
myt <- within(myt, {
  Survived <- factor(Survived, levels=c("Yes","No"))
  levels(Class) <- c(paste(c("First", "Second", "Third"), "Class"), "Crew")
  color <- ifelse(Survived=="Yes","#008888","#330066")
})

with(myt, parallelset(Survived, Sex, Class, freq=Freq, col=color, alpha=0.2))
```

Comment: Aaron, wow, fantastic answer - I wish I could mark it V twice.  Thank you!

Comment: Glad you like it.  It was fun. :)  The only tricky part is getting the places where the bars should start and end (which is in the `getp` subfunction); the rest is just drawing polygons.

Comment: One more question please, how would you add variable name to each row?

Comment: Just another `panel.text` line.  See edit.

Comment: You can do transparency in base graphics too.

Comment: Right you are. I'd completely forgotten about that, being so used to the lattice way of doing things.  For others who are interested, you add a couple more characters onto your color string, for example, `#FF000080`. `?rgb` has details.

Comment: I'm happy to see you've picked up this thread Hadley :)

Comment: Dear Aaron, I would like to ask another question - how hard will it be to have the plot flipped 90 degrees? (to have it more like a standard ||-plot?)

Comment: Shouldn't be that hard, just swap the x-axis for the y-axis everywhere.  Though the text might take some tweaking.  Try it and let me know if you get stuck.

Comment: For the text add `srt=90`.

Comment: Thanks Aaron!  I'll try it later and see how it works...

Answer (score 12):

Based on @Aaron code I developed something called "alluvial diagram". See http://bc.bojanorama.pl/2014/03/alluvial-diagrams/ Example below:

[image]

Comment: I've seen your post on r-blogges. Thanks Michal.

Comment: official package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/alluvial/