# Visualize process data

Tags: r, data-visualization, sequence-analysis

I have a dataset of order processing with 8 million rows with following columns:

- `HistoryId` - Identity column of the records
- `ItemId` - Id of the item tracked
- `Previous status` - status of Item before the history record created
- `New status` - status of Item when history record created
- `Time till status change` - The time difference between the previous record of the item till this history record created.

I want to visualized the these data with a graph / chart that displays the flow similar to this:

```
Status 1 --> Status 2 --> Status 3 --> Status 4 --> Status 5
                                       Status 5
                          Status 4 --> Status 5
Status 2 --> Status 3 --> Status 5 --> Status 2 --> Status 4 --> Status 5
                                                    Status 5
                      --> Status 4 --> Status 5
             Status 4 --> Status 5
```

In example above - assume that all of the items have:

1. First status is either `Status 1` or `Status 2`.
2. All item start with `Status 1` have 2nd status is `Status 2`, while for item start with `Status 2` partially `Status 3`, and others are `Status 4`
3. Moving on similar logic of (2.) with break down by each flow.

I want to explore the data and visualize all possible flows of the data. Then summarize them by counting the number of items go through each `Status` of each flow. Currently, I am doing them manually. Is it possible to automate this and visualize it on graph?

Sample Data:

```
HistoryID     ItemId     Previous_status     New_Status   
1             1          NA                  status_1     
2             2          NA                  status_2   
3             1          status_1            status_2   
4             1          status_3            status_4  
5             2          status_1            status_3   
6             1          status_4            status_5    
7             2          status_3            status_5
```

And here is a sample output even this output is not completely what I wanted - Explanation:

- `X` - is the index of status that an Item have in it life cycle.
- `Y` - is the status name
- `Size` - the number of item go through status Y at index X.
- Skip the color as it was exclude from the data in example.
- As you can see most of item have the status Y as the beginning status (the fist left column).
- Then moving to the right they are breaking down to other status (sometime they may come back the beginning status but in later index)
- The limitation of this is not show the flow by detail even I can see the flow by the changing in size of the point overtime.
- What I really want is something like a decision tree where you can see how item flow through the status, and each flow is separate from each others.
  [image: Sample out put but not exactly]

---

I managed to used the riverplot package. However I have some prolems as image below. Anyone know how to display the lable at the side instead of right on the spots? as I have a about 30 status and it is very confusing when having them display like the image below.

For your reference, here is the link to the package [riverplot tutorial](http://logfc.wordpress.com/2014/02/27/riverplot/)

[image]

Comment: It might just be me, but I can't discern if your sample data are supposed to correspond to the visualization concept as you've laid it out. Are the rows organized by `ItemId`? Is `Time_till_status_change` supposed to be reflected visually in any way?

Comment: The main point here is to see the general status change flow from Status 1 -> ... -> Status 5 for example. How the status change overtime. The "Time_till_status_change" doesn't need to be visualize for each item but as an average figures.
ex. Status 2 -> Status 3 average time is 2

Comment: Right, but what provides continuity to the "flow"? Are the rows organized by `ItemId`? I'm not clear on how you'd want to visualize those average times either...your example doesn't seem to include any such information. Please consider [editing](http://stats.stackexchange.com/posts/108974/edit) to clarify.

Comment: Added some clarification, remove the time to make the question focus on visualized the flow of items's statuses.

Comment: Do you want something like a Sankey diagram (see: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26578/best-way-to-visualize-attrition-using-r)?

Comment: Thank you gung! from articles you shared I found package [riverplot](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/riverplot/index.html) by January - that look interesting to tried out - I will tried it out and see if it help and update more on this article later. Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the answer to my question. There are two packages to try out:

[riverplot](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/riverplot/index.html) - this package is very flexible - as it is flexible, will need some time to learn its format to master it.

[ggparallel](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/reshape2/index.html) - easier regarding to data format which can be easily done using reshape2 package

Recently I learnt about d3.js and I think d3js is a very good tools for data visualization including for this purpose. Sample [Sankey chart](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/sankey/) drawed in d3js