# Visualization Question

Tags: r, data-visualization, python, interactive-visualization

Simple question, has anybody ever seen a similar visualization to the one below? If so what is the name of such a graph and what software could be used to create it?

[image: UK Election Visualization]

Comment: That is a Sankey graph and can be generated in many different ways including [D3](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/sankey/), or in R using various packages including [rCharts](http://timelyportfolio.github.io/rCharts_d3_sankey/example_build_network_sankey.html), which is a wrapper around D3.

Comment: Also see http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26578