# Alluvial diagram classification

Tags: time-series, data-visualization

How would you classify this diagram?  To my mind it's probably best described as a static network time-series alluvial, but I'd appreciate a second opinion as all other examples I've come across ([for example](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12029/is-it-possible-to-create-parallel-sets-plot-using-r/91588#91588)) use the approach to break down the same data observations across different facets, whereas this combines related observations over time.

[image]

Comment: I would just refer to it as a stacked area chart in which the stacks are allowed to swap positions (based on the relative ranking per point on the x axis). It also includes what appears to be a judicious amount of smoothing and slightly off-setting the stacks. I'm not quite sure what answer you are looking for though -- it is a class all by itself!

Comment: Thanks Andy. Yes it does share something with the area graph, but I think visually a ranked version (without bezier curves) might be less visually accessible.  Also I'd be a bit surprised if someone hadn't classified this approach before as it seems to have potential.

Comment: it looks a little bit like a sankey diagram, but you could browse this at your leisure to see if there's anything closer http://www.visual-literacy.org/periodic_table/periodic_table.html#

Comment: Thanks katya. The [example here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23207041/problems-parsing-data-with-the-d3-js-sankey-layout) using d3's sankey library is identical, but similarly they seem uncertainty about classification.  Nice interactive infographic-infographic btw.