# What type of chart is the best to use for the following scenario?

Tags: r, descriptive-statistics, gnuplot

I hope it is permitted to ask this type of question here.

I asked many participants to grade the fidelity (i.e resolution) of  different 3D models of different resolutions on a scale of 1 star to 5 stars (The Scale:"Bad Resolution" = 1 star, "Poor Resolution" = 2 stars, "Fair Resolution" = 3 stars, "Good Resolution" = 4 stars, and "Excellent Resolution" = 5 stars ).
I have obtained the dataset (shown in image - kindly check)
 [image]

**PS:** results are fictitious in order not to breach ethics.

Number of participants is quite high so a 3D model variation like HeadofRamesses50K will be graded on the scale of 1 to 5 by many users.

Are there any type of charts that might show correlations in such situation? Like how many percentage of participants' evaluation each model variation was graded on the 1 to 5 scale shown in a nice way? Any concrete examples in R/Gnuplot would be appreciated.

Comment: On the face of it (pun intended) you have different model names and the numbers of ratings 1 to 5. What is practical depends on how many distinct model names there are. In your example I see just 9, so a 9 x 5 bar chart of some flavour should work fine.

Comment: Welcome to [stats.se]!  Please take a moment to view our [tour].

Comment: If you want to show the relative dispersion of each of the sets of answers from your 1000 or so responses, a row of boxplots may be effective.  You could also display boxplots by resolution rating, to see if that has overall consistancy.

Comment: @Tavrock Boxplots really don't work well when the raw data are 1 2 3 4 5. Relative frequencies can be very hard to read off.

Comment: @Nick  Thank you so much for your comments and suggestions. Actually I have 17 variation of 3D models (i.e 17 different resolutions of 2 models) but I did not put them in the example for brevity. So it would be 17 *5. Not to mention 34 participants :-)  I will try to see if a barchart in R would solve this and get back to you. Thanks again.

Comment: 17 x 5 will work.  A twoway or layered bar chart as in my answer at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/148554/how-can-you-visualize-the-relationship-between-3-categorical-variables could do. Put the 17 on the vertical axis so that their names are horizontal and readable. No idea how do that in R, however.

Comment: @NickCox - just add horiz=TRUE when you make your barplot.

Comment: @G5W Thanks; I guess that is helpful to those who use R for this kind of thing (not me). (Is there only one way to do this in R?)

Comment: @NickCox That is probably the only way to use it using barplot in {graphics}. I expect that there is a way to do it with ggplot, but I am not much of a ggplot user. There may be other functions in other packages as well. I am just a BaseR kind of guy.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions. The following is what I reached so far. I wanted to create  Nick Cox's graph in R- the tabplot shown [Nick's tabplot in Stata code](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/148564/153011).

I am not successful till now. Any suggestions on  how to do that type of plot in R or Gnuplot would be greatly appreciated.

I managed to create a Mosaic plot but still need a lot of tweaking (most important a legend). I have 2 models with 17 variations. I thought I could fit them all in the same graph but the labels at top of the upper "axis" did not fit even with being perpendicular to the axis (las = 2). To solve this I used plyr package (the revalue function) to shorten names of model versions.  The following graph is for one of the models which has 7 variations of resolutions (7*5).

[image]

My R code so far is as follows:

```
mosaicplot(table(theMercuryDatawithNoInt), color = TRUE, main="", xlab = "Model Versions", ylab = "Rating with No Interaction", legend=TRUE,  cex.axis = 0.66, las = 1,direction = "v")
```

One crucial thing here is there is a lack of space for the legend. Also I don't like where the axis labels are. In addition, I am receiving the following warning as some arguments like the legend being disregarded for lack of space maybe:

> Warning message:
>   In mosaicplot.default(table(theMercuryDatawithNoInt), color = TRUE, 
>       main = "", xlab = "Model Versions", ylab = "Rating with No Interaction", 
>       legend = TRUE, cex.axis = 0.66, las = 1, direction = "v") :
>    extra arguments ‘legend’, ‘direction’ will be disregarded

Any suggestions on how to fix this. Other better answers or other graphs are also appreciated!