# What is this chart of before and after data called?

Tags: data-visualization, sankey-diagram

I saw this chart on the [BBC](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-politics-40630242) today:

[image: Before/after]

I would like to create a similar chart, but i do not know what the chart is called to learn how to build this in R.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are called [Sankey Diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sankey_diagram).

There are a few different options to create these in R. Your example could have been created with straight lines using [parallel sets](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/12029/1036). There are a few other R packages though that can make more complicated diagrams, see this [SO Q/A for some examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9968433/604456).